# Is "are want" correct in: "Women with unmet need are those who ARE WANT to stop or delay childbearing"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

I read in definition of "an unmet need" the following:

> Unmet need for family planning is defined as the percentage of women of reproductive age, either
> married or in a union, who have an unmet need for family planning. Women with unmet need are those
> who are want to stop or delay childbearing but are not using any method of contraception.
>
> [UN.org: Unmet need for family planning](https://www.un.org/en/development/desa/population/publications/dataset/contraception/wcu2014/Metadata/WCU2014_UNMET_NEED_metadata.pdf)

My question is:

Is "are want" correct in: "Women with unmet need are those who **are want** to stop or delay childbearing"?

What does that mean?

Comment: [correction: if something is grammatical, it's ok. You mean: grammar construction] That UN document is just poorly edited. [What does that mean?]

Comment: Yes, it's a mistake, among others in that passage. It's quite poorly written overall, so please don't try and learn English from it.

Comment: Please make sure you mention the source in the question, and don't "hide" it in a comment on one of the answers.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not correct. It should be

> "...are those who want to stop..."

The phrase "Women with unmet need" is *itself* somewhat awkward.
"Women with ***an*** unmet need" or "women with unmet ***needs***" would be more colloquial.

Where did you find it?

Comment: please take a look at: https://www.un.org/en/development/desa/population/publications/dataset/contraception/wcu2014/Metadata/WCU2014_UNMET_NEED_metadata.pdf

Comment: Thanks, @ilma pav. In context, the phrase does not need to be colloquial.

Comment: but the aforementioned "are want" is still wrong, right?

Comment: @ilmapav - 'are want' is either a typing o editing error.

Comment: Yes, it IS still wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the 'are' in 'are want' should be deleted, leaving

"Women with unmet need are those who want to stop or delay childbearing but are not using any method of contraception."

I will also add:

"Unmet need for family planning is defined as the percentage of women of reproductive age, either married or in a union, who have an unmet need for family planning."

Do you notice that you have defined "Unmet need for family planning" in such a way as including "unmet need for family planning"?

It's a recursive definition - the term is defined using itself.

You then provide the definition in the second sentence. You can clean this up by combining your sentences.

"Unmet need for family planning is defined as the percentage of women of reproductive age, either married or in a union, who want to stop or delay childbearing but are not using any method of contraception."

Note this removes the use of the term 'unmet need for family planning' from the defintion of 'unmet need for family planning' and thus removes the recursive definition.